# Statistical question - conditional probability

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, conditional-probability, posterior

I would like to ask below question:

i am trying to detect a kind of event by experiments, i repeat the experiment for 21 times, but no event of interest occurred.

My quesiton is based on current results (21 repeat without any occurrence), what is the reasonable estimation of probability of the event? (Or, posterior desitribution of the probaility of the event?)

Looking forward to your great ideas.

Comment: Can you provide more information? It's impossible to say based on the above.

Comment: This is not a question about conditional probability unless you provide a *prior distribution* for the probability.  As stated, it appears to be asking for a Binomial confidence interval for a count of zero.  The duplicate has a good answer.